# how to loop through table to find next minimum date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have to find out minimum start date for a member and do below steps for each member

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| memberid  | startdate |  enddate  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 200000000 | 1/3/2017  | 1/17/2017 |
| 200000000 | 1/3/2017  | 1/9/2017  |
| 200000000 | 1/10/2017 | 1/24/2017 |
| 200000000 | 1/18/2017 | 1/31/2017 |
| 200000000 | 1/18/2017 | 1/24/2017 |
| 200000000 | 1/25/2017 | 2/8/2017  |
| 200000000 | 2/17/2017 | 2/19/2017 |
| 200000000 | 2/21/2017 | 3/7/2017  |
| 200000000 | 2/21/2017 | 2/28/2017 |
| 200000000 | 3/1/2017  | 3/30/2017 |
| 200000000 | 3/3/2017  | 4/1/2017  |
| 200000000 | 3/31/2017 | 4/26/2017 |
| 200000000 | 4/27/2017 | 5/1/2017  |
| 200000000 | 5/2/2017  | 5/6/2017  |
| 200000000 | 5/7/2017  | 5/31/2017 |
| 200000000 | 5/11/2017 | 6/1/2017  |
| 200000000 | 6/5/2017  | 6/16/2017 |
| 200000000 | 6/17/2017 | 6/30/2017 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+

1.in this example, my first minimum(startdate)= 1/3/2017  . I add 30 days to it and calculated enddate is 2/2/2017. My first 30 days window is from 1/3/2017-2/2/2017. for each member this span becomes initial_1. this 30 days window is calcualted and look up table kind.
2. Similarly my second range is calcualted from second minimum start date. here my second minimum start date becomes 2/17/2017 because 1/3/2017-1/25/2017 belongs to first window range. so second 30 days range is from 
2/17/2017+30 days =3/19/2017. my second window range is from 2/17/2017-3/19/2017 . 
Third range will be from 3/31/2017(this is the next minimum start date)-4/30/2017. this is how my 30 days span is calculated. 
in each span, if servicedate <=14 days, flag it is reinitial_1 else, if servicedate > 15 days then flag it as initial_1. so in this example, my first initial ended on enddate 2/2/2017 and second started on 2/17/2017 which is >15 days from 2/2/2017 so it is flagged as initial_1. 
if date is less than 14 days then it should be flagged as reinitial.
```

My final output should be something like

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| memberid  | startdate |  enddate  |   flag    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 200000000 | 1/3/2017  | 1/17/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 1/3/2017  | 1/9/2017  | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 1/10/2017 | 1/24/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 1/18/2017 | 1/31/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 1/18/2017 | 1/24/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 1/25/2017 | 2/8/2017  | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 2/17/2017 | 2/19/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 2/21/2017 | 3/7/2017  | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 2/21/2017 | 2/28/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 3/1/2017  | 3/30/2017 | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 3/3/2017  | 4/1/2017  | Initial_1 |
| 200000000 | 3/31/2017 | 4/26/2017 | ReInitial |
| 200000000 | 4/27/2017 | 5/1/2017  | ReInitial |
| 200000000 | 5/2/2017  | 5/6/2017  | ReInitial |
| 200000000 | 5/7/2017  | 5/31/2017 | ReInitial |
| 200000000 | 5/11/2017 | 6/1/2017  | ReInitial |
| 200000000 | 6/5/2017  | 6/16/2017 | ReInitial |
| 200000000 | 6/17/2017 | 6/30/2017 | ReInitial |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I started with below logic but this is not giving me min(start date) correctly.

```
select
    memberid
    ,startdate
    ,dateadd(dd,30,min(startdate))
from #t  
group by
    memberid
    ,startdate
order by
    memberid
    ,startdate
```

It is bit complicated logic and i am not sure if i could explain clearly.
Can anyone help me with this logic?

Comment: what step 2 mean? minimun data +30 between the range, bigger than the range?

Comment: between the range.. we have to start with min(start date) and add 30 days to it.. this is comparision date now..look for all the start dates between these two dates..

Comment: btw use standard ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: sorry we use ISO only but when i copied it in Excel format changed.

Comment: I try my best but couldn't understand your logic, you talk about multiple member but only have one. Then about multiple ranges window but only have one. also not sure how work those 14-15 days, because `3/3/2017    - 4/1/2017` is bigger than your range and still is marked as initial.

Comment: this is example for only one member.. similarly we have to do for all the members. multiple range window is something we have calculate starting from minimum of start date.

Comment: You should rewrite it with a better example and more detailed explanation. Other wise we will spend a lot of time trying to guess what you need. Remember talk to us like we dont know about your problem.

Comment: consider making a [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for this

Comment: @SQLMason Maybe sqlfiddle will help, but only if we understand the logic.

Comment: thanks guys. i will try to rearrange the question in a  better way and then post it..

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry, my message was for the OP, he should make one and then show the output he expects.

Comment: @SQLMason I know. But OP already show the result he want, the problem is the logic isnt easy to match that output.

Comment: I tried my best to change the logic.

Comment: So for each member you want to break it down into 30 day windows beginning on the first startdate for that member? And for each window, if the startdate is in the first 15 days flag it as reinitial_1 and if it is in the second 15 days flag it as initial_1?

Comment: I don't understand why your first 3 months are all initial_1 and your last 3 are all reinitial in your sample output. You mention service date in some comments. Is this missing from your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right

```
SELECT memberid, startdate, enddate
   ,flag = CASE WHEN diff <=30 THEN 'Initial_1' 
           ELSE CASE WHEN diff % 31 <=14 THEN 'ReInitial' 
               ELSE 'Initial_1' END END
FROM (    
    SELECT memberid, startdate, enddate, diff = datediff(day, min(startdate) over(partition by memberid), startdate)
    FROM myTable 
     ) t
```

Comment: thank you very much... not exactly it matched..when service date is 2017-3-31 , flag has to be reinitial. because this date < 14 days from last span

Comment: Try `diff % 31 <=14` instead of `diff % 30 <=14` as every new beginning date is previous + 31